# Why is my routed component overlapping on App.js?

Tags: react-router, rendering

Now that I got my button to route to another component, I'm trying to make it render on a blank page. I thought adding target="_blank" to Link to="/blog" would make the component render on a new blank page but the component renders on the same page making my `App.js` cluttered.    [My CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/newblog-2-5-vzxvt)

Comment: Clicking the "Go to blog" button in your sandbox opens a new tab for me. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the issue though?

Comment: So when I click go to blog it opens a new window but the routed component gets rendered on the same page as App.js component. This problem is confusing since another person said the same thing you did. it rendered correctly but for me it's cluttered.

Comment: I see. Can you include a screenshot in your question for what you are seeing, and provide a bit of clarity on what you are expecting?

Comment: Check my updated CodeSandbox and look in images folder, a bit unorthodox I know I guess it's faster than email. My problem is that the routed component is rendered on App.js, too much visual clutter. https://codesandbox.io/s/newblog-2-5-vzxvt

Comment: So snippet2.png? Is that what you are expecting it to look like, or that is the "cluttered" view?

Comment: Yes that's the cluttered look I'm trying to polish. I thought adding target="_blank" to Link to="/blog" would render that component to a blank new page.